# Visual studio 2015 javascript universal app error

Tags: javascript, win-universal-app, visual-studio-2015

I have been working on a universal app with JavaScript on visual studio 2015. the application is running fine on Google chrome but when I try to run the .html file from visual studio it gives me this error. Anyone knows how to fix this?

> Unable to activate Windows Store app
>   'd12772bf-106e-4601-82de-32ac905cfdda_8wf2pzj3zhqadApp'. The
>   wwahost.exe process started, but the activation request failed with
>   error 'Windows was unable to communicate with the target application.
>   This usually indicates that the target application's process aborted.
>   More information may be available in the Debug pane of the Output
>   window (Debug->Windows->Output)'.
>
> See help for advice on troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: To which target you tried to deploy this application. in emulator on local machine.

Comment: i have tried to run it "Local Machine"

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem with some Windows insider builds, if you upgrade to Windows 10 RTM and VS2015 RTM you shouldn't have any problem.

Comment: You should ask what version of the OS and Visual Studio being used before proposing this as an answer. The reason I say this is because the issue can and does occur even in the RTM builds, perhaps because of remnants from beta builds, but this is not a solution in many cases.